# How to get count-of-a-count with dplyr?

Tags: r, count, dplyr

Let's say we have the data frame

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c"))
```

Using dplyr count, we get

```
df %>% count(x)

  x n
1 a 3
2 b 1
3 c 1
```

I now want to do a count on the resulting n column. If the n column were named m, the result I'm looking for is

```
  m n
1 1 2
2 3 1
```

How can this be done with dplyr?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You want to count the total of n or the frequency per unique element in n?

Comment: Wouldn't the total of `n` just be `nrow(df)`?

Comment: @beginneR: I meant the frequency of each unique element of n and have updated the question to be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: A base R option would be: `table(table(df$x))` or if you want it as data.frame: `as.data.frame(table(table(df$x)))`

Comment: Please state the previous version and the updated version of dplyr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr` seems to have trouble with `count(n)`.

For instance:

```
d <- data.frame(n = sample(1:2, 10, TRUE), x = 1:10)
d %>% count(n)
```

A workaround is to rename `n`:

```
df %>% # using data defined in question
  count(x) %>%
  rename(m = n) %>% 
  count(m)
```

Comment: Oh hmmmm, maybe that's a bug

Comment: @hadley If this is a bug, or if there is a more elegant solution, please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I was wrong.  Didn't have the newest version of `dplyr` so I didn't have the `count` function.

With `dplyr` a way to count is with `n()`  In your example you would do the following to obtain the first counts:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c"))

df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

Then if you want to count the occurrences of particular counts you can do:

```
 df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(count=n()) %>% group_by(count) %>% summarise(newCount=n())
```

This is a `dplyr` way.

Comment: You could still use `count`. df %>% count(x) %>% group_by(n) %>% summarize(total = n())

Comment: @jazzurro I agree. Never said you couldn't ;)

Comment: I was further trimming lines, and found this does not work. `df %>% count(x) %>% summarize(group_by(n), total = n())`

Comment: @jazzurro Right and it shouldn't.  In that case you have a major syntax error.  That `group_by(n)` in the `summarise` is trying to create a column out of the return of the `group_by` which is meaningless.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for that. :)  I was thinking something like this. `summarize(group_by(mtcars,cyl), mean(dips))` As a note, the error message was `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`

Comment: Please state the previous version and the updated version of dplyr?

Answer (score 1):

```
sum((df %>% count(x))$n)   
##[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to give data.table a try, it could be quite straight forward.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c"))
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .N, by=x][, list(count_of_N=.N), by=N]
#    N count_of_N
# 1: 3          1
# 2: 1          2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count:

```
df %>% count(x) %>% summarise(length(n))
#  length(n)
#1         3
```

If you want the sum:

```
df %>% count(x) %>% summarise(sum(n))
#  sum(n)
#1      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not pure plyr but this may work:

```
countr<-function(x){data.frame(table(x))}
t<-count(df,x)
countr(t[,2])
```